# How window.addEventListener('online') Works?

Tags: javascript, window, internet-connection, webos, lg

I am just confused Like how this window.addEventListener('online') or window.addEventListener('offline') works.
I have created An LGTV WebOS application where I have added that if any video is playing and on during play the video if internet connection is lost it should show an alert message.
So I used these window events but they only work when my wifi or network is disconnected not when I have connected to wifi but there is no internet on that.
**So what I want is alert should be displayed when I have connected to wifi but there is no internet available on wifi is there any way to do this?**

```
window.addEventListener('online', updateOnlineStatus);
window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);
function updateOnlineStatus(event) {
    console.log("-----------------Control comes into updateOnlineStatus --------------");
    console.log("event",event);
    var errorModal = document.getElementById("errorModal");
    var condition = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";
    if(condition == "online"){
        console.log("-----------INternet Is conected ----------------");
        errorModal.style.display="none";
        video.play();
    }else{
        console.log("-----------INternet Is NOOOOOOTT conected ----------------");
        video.pause();
        errorModal.style.display="block";
        SpatialNavigation.makeFocusable();
        SpatialNavigation.focus("#ok_btn");

    }
    }
```

Comment: Not from `window`. If you're in a browser, I don't think you have access to the state of the network other than connected or not. You can always just try to fetch something and see if it fails.

Comment: online and offline only tells you, whether the browser window is connected to a network or not.

Comment: so is there any way to check when it is online but have no internet  @AbhinavKumar

Comment: @Nitintiwari `fetch(someUrl).then(() => console.log("we have internet!")).catch(() => console.log("no internet :("))`

Comment: @VLAZ ok so  I have to call an API if get a successful response then internet is working otherwise not

Comment: You have to call...well, anything, really. However, you would likely want to make your own endpoint on your server that basically acts as ping (or re-use an existing one). It's the simplest solution to tell you if you have network access *to your server* because 1. being connected to a network doesn't mean you can access the interne 2. having *some* connection to the internet doesn't mean you can access your server - there might be a firewall in the way or perhaps your server is down.

Comment: Well thanks, @VLAZ got your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing a WebOS TV application, you should check first the native APIs of that platform...

[Connection Manager](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/api/webos-service-api/connection-manager/)

[Event handler](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/remaining-backward-compatible/adding-event-handler/)

[WebOS services](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/api/webos-service-api/using-webos-services/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a connection status by using the webOsDev.js library of WebOS.

```
webOSDev.connection.getStatus({
    onSuccess: function (res) {
        if (res.isInternetConnectionAvailable === false) {
            //when the internet connection is not available 
        } else {
            //when internet is available
        }
    },
    onFailure: function (res) {
        //on failure to request the API
    },
    subscribe: true
});
```